# WPF Validation Errors: Setting Tooltip with Error Message

Tags: wpf, validation, templates

Why is there no tooltip text on errors?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border ...>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder ... 
                            ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                    </Border>
                    ...
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I also noticed that

```
<AdornedElementPlaceholder ...
    ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
```

fails but the below suceeds, even with the same binding, why is this so? Doesn't `AdornedElementPlaceholder` refer to the text box? Even if it doesn't, shouldn't a tooltip appear somewhere?

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't place a tooltip on the AdornedElementPlaceholder, I don't think it's visible at all, it's just reserving space for whoever uses it (in your case a TextBox). Looking at the Visual Tree with Snoop we can see that the TemplatedAdorner ends up in a different place in the VisualTree than the TextBox so there will be now way for us to find the TextBox from the VisualTree. We can find it through AdornedElement, but we still won't be able to set a tooltip.

[image]

The only thing visible here in the TemplatedAdorner is the Border. The Border knows its Child - the TemplatedAdorner - which in turn knows its AdornedElement - the TextBox. So we could set the ToolTip for the Border with this. (However, this Binding seems to fail to update the Tooltip for the Border. It works when I look at it with Snoop and after that it displays.)

```
<Border BorderBrush="Red"
        BorderThickness="4"
        ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self},
                  Path=Child.AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
```

So, the TextBox has its AttachedProperty Validation where we can find the ErrorContent so it must set its own ToolTip like you did at your last example, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Solution is fine, but to avoid exceptions in your Output.Debug window I'd make your ToolTip binding ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self},
                  Path=Child.AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"

Answer (score 26):

I know I'm late, but let me share a solution I found studying this question: [WPF custom validator with tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3106132/620360).

In it's simplest form this `ErrorTemplate` shows only a `Tooltip` with the `ErrorContent` for the whole `AdornedElement`.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
    <Grid Background="Transparent"
          ToolTip="{Binding Path=/ErrorContent}">
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

But of course you can decorate it as desired e.g. with a `Tooltip` for just a marker.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Fill="Red" Opacity="0.8" Width="10" Height="10"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 ToolTip="{Binding Path=/ErrorContent}" />
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

---

Put this `Template` in `Resources` and all you have to do is setting the `Validation.ErrorTemplate`.

```
Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
```

Even this annoying Trigger is no longer needed.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: That’s a good idea; unfortunately your first solution will put a (transparent) overlay over the whole text box preventing the user from focussing it and correcting the error.

Comment: @poke You're right. First solution is only useful for controls showing an error. But maybe the second solution is anyway what you want.

Comment: The second solution works fine for a TextBox, but not for a ComboBox.  I can't click on the ComboBox at all if I have IsHitTestVisible set to true, which seems to be necessary in order to get the ToolTip to work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @MattZappitello Just tried it with a ComboBox and had no problems (ToolTip is showing without any code changes). I think the issue is caused somewhere else.

Comment: @LPL - The ToolTip showed up just fine, but I then could not click on the ComboBox to get the dropdown to appear.  If I set IsHitTestVisible to false, I could interact with the ComboBox, but the ToolTip wouldn't show up.  Were you able to interact with the ComboBox and see the ToolTip?

Comment: @MattZappitello Yes, both was functional. Maybe your validationTemplate Grid inherits a Background from somewhere? You could try setting Background to `{x:Null}`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to implement `ToolTip` with the returned error message from the validation class that you might create to validate your input.

#### First: Binding the error message

Adding `<Style>` for the `TextBox` with `Style.Trigger` as followed:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="ToolTipError">
    <!-- Some style setters -->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

#### Second: Add the style to `TextBox`

```xml
<TextBox 
    Style="{StaticResource ToolTipError}"
    Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding 
            Path="YourViewModelProperty"
            UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
            ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors="True"
            ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"
            NotifyOnValidationError="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule:DateValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

#### Bonus!

You can change the ugly red border with other thing.
For example you can change it to red exclamation mark:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="26" Foreground="Red"/>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
<Window.Resources>
```