# How to create a tooltip to display multiple validation errors for a single control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, validation

I am trying to display multiple validation errors for a control through a tooltip over the control, but am not finding a way to do this.

I can easily display a single validation error for a control through a tooltip with a style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

[image]

However, this approach only lets me display the first validation error. I have tried to get a list of validation errors in the tooltip, but the list never displays. Below are the approaches I have tried:

Placing an ItemsControl in the tooltip, using Validation.Errors as the ItemsSource and CurrentItem.ErrorContent as the text to display:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ItemsControl>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                                <Binding Path="(Validation.Errors)" RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}" />
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I have also tried using Validation.Errors.CurrentItem as the ItemsSource, and ErrorContent as the text to display:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ItemsControl>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                                <Binding Path="(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem" RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}" />
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Any of these approaches result in an empty tooltip being displayed:

[image]

I CAN display a list of validation errors for a control as a list outside of the control, using the Validation.ErrorTemplate:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

[image]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161523/wpf-validation-errors-setting-tooltip-with-error-message/14550973#14550973) answer shows how to place errors in a separate elements tooltip using the ErrorTemplate. It seems that when within the ErrorTemplate, you have access to the full list of errors, which you don't seem to have in the Tooltip style as I tried above. The first solution in the answer renders the control unclickable, which I don't want. I attempted the second solution in the answer here:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Fill="Red" Opacity="0.8" Width="10" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Ellipse.ToolTip>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </Ellipse.ToolTip>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This does give me a tooltip with all errors for the control:

[image]

However you have to hover over the red circle for the tooltip to appear. My goal is for the tooltip to appear when you hover over the control, which I think will be more intuitive for the users. I just can't seem to find out how to put multiple errors into the actual control tooltip. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I know this Question was posted some time ago but I had the same problem and wanted to share my solution (hope it helps others ;) ).

After googeling for a bit I found a [post](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/785207/wpf-validation-does-only-show-the-first-element-from-inotifydataerrorinfo-geterrors) that described kinda this problem. They suggested to solve this with a MultiBinding and thats what I did. I used only a style to do this
here the code for the style:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" /> 
                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(Validation.Errors)" />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="(Validation.Errors).Count" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The Problem is that (Validation.Errors) gets you a ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ValidationError> and this collection will be filled over time. But when you bind to the (Validation.Errors) it will only notice the first item. Thats the reason for the second binding (Validation.Errors).Count so that every time the Count is changed your converter will be called. 

Now finally we need the Converter:

```
public class MultiLineConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(values[0] is IEnumerable<ValidationError>))
            return null;

        var val = values[0] as IEnumerable<ValidationError>;

        string retVal = "";

        foreach (var itm in val)
        {
            if (retVal.Length > 0)
                retVal += "\n";
            retVal += itm.ErrorContent;

        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

It only uses the values[0] since that is the collection. And then it will create a string for all ErrorContents.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works as I expected! But there is need to be careful about values[0], that IEnumerable can be at any position in array (I think it depends on order which attributes are placed).

Comment: Well yes it depends on how you set it up in your xaml. If one were to generalize it you would probably go looking for an IEnumerable<ValidationError> in your values array. If you find one good else return null

Comment: This does not seem to work for errors associated with a DataGridRow. Only the first error is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but I was stuck on this for a while, amd found a way I prefer. 
It doesn't turn your validation errors into a string, but uses ItemsControl instead, which makes more sense to me.

A tooltip isn't part of the window's visual tree, but you can still create a style for it. `Validation.Errors` is the collection of `ValidationError` objects.

```
<Style x:Key="validationTooltipStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)}" Background="#FFDC000C" Margin="0 0 3 0">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" Foreground="#FFFFFF"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
</Style>
```

Instantiate a tooltip resource

```
<ToolTip x:Key="validationTooltip" Style="{StaticResource validationTooltipStyle}"/>
```

Finally set it to trigger when your target has errors

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource validationTooltip}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for errors associated with a DataGridRow. Only the first error is displayed.