# wpf validation: showing multiple errors for each field

Tags: c#, wpf

`INotifyDataErrorInfo` supports multiple error for each field, that's useful for my application.
When it comes to display them on the UI, a strategy is needed not to overlap with other controls.
[image]

The code currently is straightforward:

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path='Editing.Id', 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                    ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}">
        <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
    </TextBox>
```

What I would like to get: 
[image]

That is: the first error gets always displayed; this cover the most-frequent case of one validation exception only.
If there are more than one, a "And other errors" text is displayed and clicking on it or moving the mouse over it you get the remainder ones.
I'm looking for this exact solution or for any alternative solution of displaying multiple errors that is  more clean from an implementation point of view. In particular I would like to have an implementation xaml-only.

In the case of this implementation, i don't know how to handle the different way of representing the first and the subsequent items.

I considered [How to create a tooltip to display multiple validation errors for a single control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627368/how-to-create-a-tooltip-to-display-multiple-validation-errors-for-a-single-contr) that for sure addresses the same problem, but focusing on a specific solution, that is the tooltip one. 
Here I wanted to open the discussion to different available solutions for a problem that is general and needs sort of a standardized approach.

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve what you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a tooltip to display multiple validation errors for a single control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627368/how-to-create-a-tooltip-to-display-multiple-validation-errors-for-a-single-contr)

Comment: You could either use a tooltip with an itemscontrol in it, or you could show all the errors in a big list or you could make mouseover on a control or some part of a custom error template show just the errors for that control in a listbox/ itemscontrol which expands to fit them.